# upgrading cloudera manager from cdh 5.4.9 to 5.6.0

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

when i'm trying to upgrade cloudera manager via CM parcel page (at: http://hostname:7180/cmf/parcel/status) i get the flowing errors:

> Local parcel error for parcel CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45-el6.parcel : The version 5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45 is too new to be supported. Please upgrade Cloudera Manager to at least 5.6.0 before using this parcel..

when trying to activate the parcel i get the following error:

> The new version of CDH: '5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45' is newer than the running Cloudera Manager version: '5.4.8'.

how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your cloudera manager is older version. So first update your manager then try to upgrade your cluster. Refer below link for more details

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/install_upgrade_to_cdh56.html